# TextView set Text and Color are simply ignored

Tags: android, textview, http-post

I am a total newbie to Android and this is my first Application. I have been running into this problem the last few days and just give up searching for an answer. I would very much appreciate some help on this.

The method sendSelectedItem is called when a button is clicked. In the else if clause the methods setTvText and setTvColor are simply ignored, they are supposed to set the Text and Color of a TextView but don't do a thing. What follows is a httpPOST request on a php script on my webserver, that returns a simple String, this part works fine.

```
    public void sendSelectedItem(View v){

    if(v == findViewById(R.id.btnCancel)){
        setTvText("nothing happens");
        setTvColor(0);
    }
    else if (v == findViewById(R.id.btnSend)){
        setTvText("selection transmitted");
        setTvColor(1);

        /*SelectedItemHttpPost si = new SelectedItemHttpPost();
        try {
            String retResp = si.executeHttpPost(selectedItem);
            setTvText(retResp);
            setTvColor(2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){};*/
    }

}
```

Do you have an idea, why the setTvText and setTvColor are executed only if the remaining Code is commented out, as depicted above?

In case it helps, I paste the code of SelectedItemHttpPost.
Thank you very much.

```
public class SelectedItemHttpPost{

private HttpClient client = null;
private HttpPost request = null;
private HttpResponse response = null;
private List<NameValuePair> postParameters = null;
private UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = null;
private String responsePHP = "";
private BufferedReader in = null;
private StringBuffer sb = null;


public SelectedItemHttpPost(){
}

public String executeHttpPost(String selectedItem) throws Exception{
    try{
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    request = new HttpPost("http://www.somedomain.com/test/test.php");
    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg1", selectedItem));
    formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);

    request.setEntity(formEntity);
    response = client.execute(request);
    in = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent())));

    sb = new StringBuffer("");
    sb.append(in.readLine());
    in.close();
    responsePHP = sb.toString();

    return responsePHP;
    }
finally     {}
}
```

}

Comment: You need to post full code, include the setTvColor methods

Comment: Woah are you sure they are being ignored? You are doing the entire HTTP request socket creation and parsing all on the UI Thread. So you probably are seeing something like the button being pressed ... and then the screen doesn't respond since the thread that draws is actually listening for data on the network blocking any further interaction until that completes? If so use an AsyncTask with the HttpPost executed on the doInBackground() and the setTvColor and setTvText on the postExecute()

Comment: Thanks very much. I would never have tought of Threads. That is a totally new thing to me - I see a long way ahead of me. I will elaborate on that and hopefully be able to implement my first app successfully. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate method you need to create a button object, something like:

```
btnCancel = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnCancel);
```

and then access the button object while clicking on it:

```
if(v == btnCancel)
{
        setTvText("nothing happens");
        setTvColor(0);
}
```